# Some properties of Yosida-Moreau transform

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x) \geqslant 0$ for any $x$. Define
$$
   f_{\alpha}(x) = \inf\limits_{y}\left( f(y) +\frac{|x-y|^2}{2\alpha} \right)
$$
where $\alpha > 0$. How to show that $f_{\alpha}(x)$ is locally Lipschitz continuous and $f_{\alpha} \to f$ when $\alpha \to 0+0$ uniformly  on any compact $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you want the inf to be over $y \in K$?  In general the inf could be $-\infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's right. In my case $f(x)$ has a particular type. I'll correct a little my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us restrict attention to $|x|\le R$. Let $M=\sup_{|x|\le R}f$. The main observation is that the infimum can be taken only over $y$ such that $|x-y|\le \sqrt{2\alpha M}$. Indeed, when $|x-y|>\sqrt{2\alpha M}$, the second term makes the sum greater than $M$, hence greater than $f(x)$.

1) Let $R'=R+\sqrt{2\alpha M}$. For any fixed $y$ such that $|y|\le R'$, the function $x\mapsto f(y)+|x-y|^2/(2\alpha)$ is Lipschitz with a constant $L=L(R',\alpha)$. It is easy to see that the infimum of any family of $L$-Lipschitz functions is $L$-Lipschitz (or $\equiv -\infty$, which is what we rule out with a lower bound for $f$).

2) is now easy: if $\alpha$ is small, $\sqrt{2\alpha M}$ is small, so the infimum will not be far away from $f(x)$ by the uniform continuity of $f$ on $\{|x|\le R'\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question about second part: the infumum is taken over $y \colon |x-y|^2 \leqslant 2 \alpha M$, then what if the minimizer $y'$ is such that $|x-y'|^2 = 2\alpha M$? Then we have $f_{\alpha}(x) = f(y') + M$

Comment: @Nimza Notice that $f_\alpha(x)\le f(x)$ by definition, so the only question is whether the infimum can be much smaller than $f(x)$. It can't because the infimum is taken over a neighborhood in which $f$ is not far from $f(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't noticed. Merci.