# Continuity of pointwise infimum (of a special function); Moreau-Yosida regularisation

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, regularization, envelope

I'm seeking how to prove that Moreau-Yosida regularisation provides a continuous function:
Given a convex function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a compact subspace of an Euclidean space (namely, $\mathbb{R}^n)$, Moreau-Yosida regularisation, $g_{\eta}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function for any $\eta > 0$ where $g_{\eta} (x) = \inf_{x' \in X} \left( \frac{1}{2 \eta} \lVert x - x' \rVert^2 + f(x') \right )$ for all $x \in X$.

It is well-known that the gradient of $g_{\eta}$ is a Lipschitz continuous (so obviously $g_{\eta}$ is continuous) but I don't know how to prove the Lipschitzness.

The main question is whether $g_{\eta}$ is a continuous function for any fixed $\eta > 0$ or not. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I do not see how $g_\eta$ depends on $\eta$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Sorry, it was my mistake. I corrected the above equation.

Comment: Does [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162502/some-properties-of-yosida-moreau-transform) answers you question?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!