# Is this function continuous? (Moreau-Yosida regularisation with additional function argument)

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, regularization

I'm considering a generalised form of Moreau-Yosida regularisation.

Given a continuous function $f:X \times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x, \cdot)$ is convex for any $x \in X$ and $X$, $U$ compact subspaces of Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, resp., consider this parameterised function $f_{\eta}: X \times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f_{\eta}(x, u) = \inf_{v \in U} \left(\frac{1}{2 \eta} \lVert u - v \rVert^2 + f(x, v)\right)$ for any $\eta > 0$.

I wonder if $f_{\eta}$ is also a continuous function for given $\eta > 0$.
In [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213564/continuity-of-pointwise-infimum-of-a-special-function-moreau-yosida-regularis), the continuity of standard Moreau-Yosida regularisation can be shown by that the infimum of Lipschitz continuous functions is also Lipschitz continuous (A fortiori, it is continuous). However, in this case, I have no idea how to show the continuity with respect to the arguments $(x, u)$.

Can anybody help me? :)

Comment: Since $U$ is compact it is straightforward to check that $f_\nu$ is upper & lower semi continuous using sequences.

Comment: @copper.hat If you don't mind, can you share your answer in detail?

Comment: @copper.hat I think that you were trying to say [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66462/711836), that is, minimum or maximum function over a compact set is a continuous function. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, just say your comment, yes that it what I meant, sorry I was not more clear. Yes another answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674559/27978

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you!